# Why does lwarpmk limages command does generate empty svg image files?

Tags: tikz-pgf, latex2html, lwarp

Using lwarp commands, I'm trying to generate an html page from a .tex file containing a tikzpicture section.

Compiling and generating pdf version succeeds !

Generating html file with the `lwarpmk html` command succeeds.

When executing the `lwarpmk limages` command, an error occurs :

```
Link from 'myFile-images\lateximagetemp-##.pdf' to '`tmp-pdfcrop-10720-img.pdf' failed (Operation not permitted/Le client ne dispose pas d'un privilège nécessaire)!
```

Then

```
C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:921: command failed with exit code 2:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\pdfcrop\pdfcrop.pl --hires --margins "0 1 0 0" Latexemple06-images\lateximagetemp-12.pdf Latexemple06-images\image-1.pdf
I/O Error: Couldn't open file 'Latexemple06-images\image-1.pdf': No error.
Error opening PDF file.
Impossible de trouver D:\oneDrive\Guillaume\Maths\Latex\Latexemple06-images\image-1.pdf"
```

No pdf files is present in the images subfolder.
Only a svg empty file.

See image.

Distribution : Texlive 2023.
OS : Windows 10 Pro 64 bits.

Thanks for help !

Regards.

Comment: Welcome, stop the onedrive sync and try again...you have a permissions (or write) problem, otherwise try a non-synchronised directory...And place an MWE so you can test from this side :D

Comment: Thank you Pablo for your help !
The onedrive wasn't the real problem : I had the same in a non-synchrones directory.
Fortunately, you put me in the right direction : I opened a cmd window "as an adminisrator", and then I succeeded generating my svg subfolder files and my html latex file.
Thank you very much !
Guillaume